# Can I use Fluent API to pass HashSet via constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-5.0

I've got a domain model structured like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly HashSet<int> _intSet;
    public IReadOnlySet<int> Intset => _intSet;
    public Foo(HashSet<int> intSet)
    {
        _intSet = intSet;
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to use EF's Fluent API to persist it, but I keep getting the `InvalidOperationException` stating that:

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Foo'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'intSet' in 'Foo(HashSet<int> intSet).'

I've tried using the `ModelBuilder` options shown below, unfortunatelly to no avail:

```
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Foo>()
            .Property(p => p.Intset)
            .HasField("_intSet")
            .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.FieldDuringConstruction);
```

Is there any actual way to make this work? Note that I definitely do not want to use `DataAnnotations`.

Answer (score 0):

EF models should have a parameterless constructor

Something like this should work:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public Hashset<int> Intset { get; set;}
}
```

But you will lose that read-only policy.

If you want to keep that feature you should make some DTO class which would look like this

```cs
public class FooDto
{
    private readonly HashSet<int> _intSet;
    public IReadOnlySet<int> Intset => _intSet;
    public FooDto(HashSet<int> intSet)
    {
        _intSet = intSet;
    }
}
```

and then use that DTO with some mapping in vanilla style like this (or use mapping library like `Automapper`)

```
var fooDto = new FooDto(foo.Intset);
```